# How do i remove these random integers(which is I did not input at all) when I load a .txt file into my program

Tags: c++, string, file, linked-list

I am currently doing an assignment in C++ in which I have to load a bunch of data from a `.txt` file into a linked list:

[image]

Here is my load code:

```
void record::load( string fileName ) throw( recordException )
{
    ifstream inFile( fileName.c_str() );
    string c;
    string t;
    double p;
    int q;
    node *tail;

    while (!isEmpty())
    {
        remove( 1 );
    }
    size = 0;

    if ( getline(inFile, c) ||getline(inFile,t)||inFile >> p>> q) // Is file empty?
    {  // File not empty:
        try
        {
            head = new node;
            // Add the first integer to the list.
            head->cat = c;
            head->title = t;
            head->price = p;
            head->qty = q;
            head->next = NULL;
            tail = head;
            size = size + 1;
            inFile.skipws;

            // Add remaining items to linked list.
            while ( getline(inFile, c)||getline(inFile ,t)||inFile >> p>> q)
            // while(inFile.getline(c,50)||inFile.getline(t,50)||inFile>>p>>q)
            {
                tail->next = new node;
                tail = tail->next;
                tail->cat = c;
                tail->title = t;
                tail->price = p;
                tail->qty = q;
                tail->next = NULL;
                size = size + 1;
                inFile.skipws;
            }  // end while
        }  // end try
        catch (bad_alloc e)
        {
            throw recordException(
                "recordException: restore cannot allocate memory.");
        }  // end catch
    }  // end if

    inFile.close();
}
```

It works great, except for one issue: I get really weird numbers when I try to display the data that is loaded in my linked list.

This is what it looks like when my program runs:

[image]

Can anyone help me? What can I do to remove those numbers? Why do these numbers occur anyway?

I am using C++ Codeblocks 16.01, if that is of any help.

Comment: `if ( getline(inFile, c) ||getline(inFile,t)||inFile >> p>> q)` shouldn't this be `&&` instead of `||`?

Comment: **Use a debugger** like `gdb` (and compile with all warnings & debug info, e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`)

Comment: What does the file actually look like? No matter what, `getline(inFile, c) || getline(inFile,t) || inFile >> p>> q` is certainly not the right way to read the file. And what does the code look like that is displaying the data?

Comment: I recommend overloading `operator>>` for your node class.  The node should be able to load its members from a stream, as node has the knowledge and direct access.  Accessing node members is a violation of the encapsulation rule.

Comment: BTW, you may want to change your design so that a function creates node content (from the input file), then inserts into the list.  The list should have limited knowledge of the environment outside of the list structure.

Comment: @RemyLebeau if I try 
getline(inFile,c) && getline(inFile,t) && inFile >>p>>q
the file would refuse to be loaded i.e. size = 0 and no records displayed. The file looks exactly like the output without the weird numbers at the back.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I tried overloading the operator but then it would refuse to display. I checked some other posts and they said it was because i have to output a string complete with spaces :( 

For the 2nd suggestion, do you mean that instead of inputting into the node directly i create another function then input that function into the list? I'm not too sure as i'm a newbie so it would be really nice if you could provide a little demonstration. Thank you!

Comment: @WeeNing I wasn't suggesting you use `getline(inFile,c) && getline(inFile,t) && inFile >>p>>q`. Do you even understand what that code is doing? Mixing multiple calls to `getline()` with `operator>>` in this manner just looks wrong. And the output you showed does not match such code, so the output is clearly not the same as the input. That is why I asked you to show the actual input. You have errors in your reading logic, but noone can tell you what they are without seeing the exact input.

Comment: @RemyLebeau
Here is the [input](http://imgur.com/EfrPdQu), slight changes because I tried altering the spacing and all but it is still the same output 


I am not too sure how else can I call my items from a node(I have 5 items -> int, string, string, double, int). Do you have any suggestions how I can do that (albeit my string must include spaces?)??

Here is the retrieve code I [used](http://imgur.com/qWWFvIN) i.e. I retrieved the items from the linked list I loaded into the program and then displayed it all using cout.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]

Comment: You cannot split that lines this way, you need to read it line by line and then split using RE or manually written logic.

Answer (score 0):

Next time, don't use images, always copy/paste the actual text into your post instead.

Your reading code does not match the format of your input data.  When you call `getline()`, it reads until it encounters a line break or EOF.

So, the first call to `getline(inFile, c)` reads the ENTIRE first line in one go:

```
"     DVD     Snow White          20     20"
```

Then `getline(inFile,t)` reads the NEXT line in one go:

```
"     VCD     Cinderella          10     10"
```

Then `inFile >> p >> q` tries to parse the NEXT line and fails:

```
"     MT      Wonderworld         20     30"
```

Since `MT` is not a `double` and `Wonderworld` is not an `int`.

You need to read the file line-by-line, parsing each line individually, for example:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

void record::load( std::string fileName ) throw( recordException )
{
    while (!isEmpty())
        remove( 1 );
    size = 0;

    std::ifstream inFile( fileName.c_str() );
    if (!inFile.is_open())
        return;

    std::string line;
    std::string c;
    char t[25+1] = {0}; // <-- use whatever your max title length actually is...
    double p;
    int q;
    node *newNode;

    while (std::getline(inFile, line)) // Is file empty?
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);

        if ((iss >> c) && iss.get(t, sizeof(t)) && (iss >> p >> qty))
        {
            try
            {
                newNode = new node;
                newNode->cat = c;
                newNode->title = t;
                newNode->price = p;
                newNode->qty = q;
                newNode->next = NULL;

                if (!head)
                    head = newNode;

                if (tail)
                    tail->next = newNode;
                tail = newNode;
                ++size;
            }
            catch (const bad_alloc &e)
            {
                throw recordException(
                    "recordException: restore cannot allocate memory.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression is much more suitable for task like this. You can use something like:

```
std::string test = "      DVD      Snow White       20    20";
std::regex re("\\s*(\\S+)\\s+(\\S.*\\S)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)");
std::smatch match;
if (std::regex_match(test, match, re)) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < match.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << "submatch " << i << ": \"" << match[i] << "\"\n";
        }   
 }
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/cys2u6)

So you could read file line by line and split it using that RE:

```
std::regex re("\\s*(\\S+)\\s+(\\S.*\\S)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)");
std::string line;
while( std::getline( inFile, line ) ) {
    std::smatch match;
    if (!std::regex_match(test, match, re)) continue;
    std::string cat = match[1].str();
    std::string title = match[2].str();
    double price = std::stod( match[3].str() );
    int qty = std::stoi( match[4].str() );
    // you insert your node into list here 
}
```

Note: I made RE pattern based on your input - price contains only digits, no dot. If it is not the case you would need to modify RE accordingly.